# Count amount of rows in database with the same value in two columns - Use amount of top 5 rows to set width of 5 different divs

Tags: php, mysql, loops, count

```
id     company_id     company_name     size_of_company     employee 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1             Comp 1              Big              John
2         1             Comp 1              Big              Ann  
3         1             Comp 1              Big              Peter
4         2             Comp 2              Big              Lisa 
5         2             Comp 2              Big              Steve 
6         3             Comp 3              Big              Mike  
7         3             Comp 3              Big              Anna  
8         3             Comp 3              Big              Jon   
9         3             Comp 3              Big              Nick  
10        3             Comp 3              Big              May   
11        4             Comp 4              Big              Lee   
12        4             Comp 4              Big              James 
13        4             Comp 4              Big              Jess  
14        4             Comp 4              Big              Carrie
15        5             Comp 5              Big              Luke  
16        5             Comp 5              Big              Brad  
17        5             Comp 5              Big              Joan  
18        5             Comp 5              Big              Ruth  
19        5             Comp 5              Big              Joel  
20        6             Comp 6              Big              Paul
```

This is probably an easy question, but my skills are quite low when it comes to MySQL and PHP. I have tried different loops with no result at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

**What I want to do is this:**

How do I count the amount of rows with the same company_id and size_of_company and then collect the amount of rows for the  top 5 along with the names of the top 5 companies?

The amount of rows will be used in a div as width value for the div. The div shall be printed 5 times with different width value. The more rows the bigger div.

There will also be values of Medium and Small in size_of_company. But a company_name can only have one size_of_company. These two other size_of_company shall also be printed on the page, under their own category, Medium or Small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the following would count the number of rows with the same company_id, company_name and size_of_company (using GROUP BY). Ordering and then limiting the number of results gives you the top 5.

```
SELECT
 t.company_id,
 t.company_name,
 COUNT(*)
FROM
 tble t
GROUP BY
 t.company_id, t.company_name, t.size_of_company
ORDER BY
 COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I have come a bit on the way, but when I try this and do a while loop for the 5 divs I get this result: 13425. Shouldn't it be the highest amount first 54321? So the first div gets the value 5, the next 4 and so on?

Comment: @Fredrik could you post some of you PHP code? If you are ordering correctly in the SQL query, then the issue probably lies in the PHP code calling it. Also try running your query in the MySQL command line directly to make sure the result is as you expect.

Comment: trf, I got it to work now. Added c after the first COUNT( * ).

SELECT
t.company_id
t.company_name,
COUNT(*) c
FROM new_members t
WHERE size_of_company='$size'
GROUP BY t.company_id, t.company_name
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
LIMIT 5

and in the while loop I echo row c and row company_name.

Thanks a lot for your help!